# How do I prevent focus on form (at bottom of page) when page loads?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My page contains a form at the bottom. When the page loads the browser gives focus to the form, when what I want is for the top of page to be shown.

The form is:

```
<section class="item" id="form_text">
    <form id="form" name="queryForm" action="proc_query.php" method="get">
        <input type="text" size="40" name="name"  autofocus required placeholder="Name"><br><br>
        <input type="text" size="40" name="phoneNum" placeholder="Phone No."><br><br>
        <input type="email" size="40" name="email" placeholder="Email" required><br><br>
        <textarea required rows="8" cols="41" name="comments" placeholder="Comments"> </textarea><br><br>
        <input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Query">
    </form>
</section>
```

I've tried assigning focus to an element at the top of the page but that hasn't worked:

`function getfocus() {
    document.getElementById("mi").focus();
}`

Can you suggest a solution?

Comment: Remove `autofocus` on your `name` input.

Comment: Tried that....didn't work.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/n0kkdeb0/ Works perfectly. If it really doesn't work for you, it may be caused by something else. Post your whole code.

Comment: Have you cleared/disabled cache? What input is it focusing on? Can you make a fiddle duplicating the issue?

Comment: Removing the autofocus works for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

Removing autofocus from name input works for me too. Inspect element to see if it has been removed/Clear cache.

Comment: OK thanks to all. I've proven, with 3 different browsers, that removing autofocus fixes the issue. I thought I'd tried that before posting the question but may be not properly.